# Advice for investing money for a 15-year old

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, pension, savings-account

Hope this is on-topic for here.

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to handle a pension. I would like to have the money paid into an account for my 15-year old daughter. The lump sum is about £10,000, and there would be a monthly income of around £330.

The problem I have is that from searching around, it seems that any account that gives anything like a decent interest rate is either only for adults (ie over 16, which she isn't) or has a maximum of £100 monthly income.

She doesn't have any other income, and we aren't anticipating any for her for the next few years.

Anyone able to advise what would be a good way to handle this? She doesn't need instant access to the money.

We're in the UK.

Comment: Reality check: 330/month is 4000/year, which is 40% of the PV.  It's much more likely that 10,000 will earn 330/year, not per month.  Or is the "lump sum" a separate payment and unrelated to the monthly?

Comment: @BenVoigt The £10K is a lump sum, separate from the monthly amount. Thanks

Comment: in para 2 you mention a pension, is this the _source_ of the funds you want to give to your daughter?

Comment: I have to mention that if this is your pension you are about to receive, and you are hoping to avoid paying tax on it by transferring it to your daughter, that won't work. Pensions are your income and can't be transferred except in very exceptional circumstances. You can of course give your daughter the money after you have paid the tax on it.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thanks for pointing that out. No, I'm not trying to avoid tax here, I just want to give my daughter something to get her going in life. I leave the tax stuff to my accountant.

Comment: Is there a reason you anticipate saving these funds as a pension [implying, for retirement]? There are probably a few dozen financial goals that will happen before your daughter retires; things like saving for first car / rent down payment / college / house etc. etc.; I ask because saving for 50 years from now requires different strategies than saving for 2 years from now.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. The pension is mine, I just want to put it into an account for my young daughter for her future. I was thinking more about when she gets to the stage of wanting to set up her own home. It's me that's retired, not her!

Answer (score 10):

Note that if your child makes more than £100/year in interest from money you give them, then [you have to pay tax on it anyway](https://www.gov.uk/savings-for-children). [A previous version of my answer talked about £100/month because I got months and years mixed up :-)]

You can use a Junior ISA which doesn't have that problem, it looks like there are [some around offering 4-5% interest](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/junior-isa/) right now.

You can also consider taking more risk with the money by investing it in stocks (like an index fund) if it won't be needed for a few years and it wouldn't be a disaster if some was lost.

Remember that anything you put in her name now becomes hers to do what she wants with when she reaches 18.

Comment: Thanks for that, a junior ISA looks like a good option. Need to do some reading.